# How to resolve error code "maxVizResizeAttempts" - 'Viz resize limit hit. The calculated iframe size did not stabilize after 10 resizes.'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tableau-api, iframe-resizer

I am using trial version to see if it fits my needs but getting error: 'Viz resize limit hit. The calculated iframe size did not stabilize after 10 resizes.'

my code is as follows

```
<div id="vizContainer">
    </div>



function initViz() {

var containerDiv = $('#vizContainer'),

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";

containerDiv.css("border", "3px double red");

var options = {
    width: containerDiv.offsetWidth,
    height: containerDiv.offsetHeight
    
};
console.log(containerDiv.width());
var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
}
```

I have also tried adding width and height as follows

```
<div id="vizContainer" style="width:1900px; height:500px"></div>
```

but still getting same issue:
[image]
Besides I have another issue in browser (not sure if its related)

> Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute

Comment: Hi Samra,
Did you able to figure out this problem? Please share if you had. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: hi @PankajParkar unfortunately, we stopped trialling tableau